# Is this a relevant question? Tor links from Wikipedia

Tags: discussion

I've spent an hour or so this evening browsing around trying to figure out why the Wikipedia software doesn't allow links to *.onion domains (eg. in citations). Trying to add one results in an error message.

There's been some discussion/controversy around this on Wikipedia itself. Is a [self-answered question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) explaining it all on-topic (given that it's not precisely about Tor itself, but issues around it)?

[More info.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Assassination_market#.22Wikipedia_does_not_allow_the_URL_of_this_source.22)

Comment: Got around to doing it :-) http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/why-cant-i-link-to-onion-domains-from-wikipedia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds reasonable to me; it's definitely "about Tor" even if it's not directly related to the software itself and it doesn't fall into any of the categories that are generally frowned upon (primarily opinion based, too broad, hypothetical/open ended, etc).

When in doubt, "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" in the help center is a good reference.